# Ingress.yaml template is throwing nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I try to do `helm install <chartname> . -f values.yaml -n namespace`, i am getting:

```
 Error: template: pid-dm-rd-guacamole/templates/ingress.yaml:1:8: executing "pid-dm-rd-guacamole/templates/ingress.yaml" at <$.Values.ingress.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled
```

Can anyone please suggest how we can avoid this error, here I have attached my `ingress.yaml` and ingress section in `values.yaml`

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "device-management.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "device-management.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

```
ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: 
      ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
      certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    paths: []
    #  - backend:
    #      serviceName: ssl-redirect
    #      servicePort: use-annotation
    #  - backend:
    #      # Don't use string here, use only integer value!
    #      servicePort: 443
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "off"
    path: /
    hosts:
      #what is the hostname?
       - host: guacamole.****.corp.com
         paths:
           - path: /
             backend:
               serviceName: guacamole.****.corp.com
               servicePort: 80
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - guacamole.danaher.corp.com
```

Comment: What is in your `values.yaml` file (possibly as amended by `helm install -f` options)?  You'd get that error if there was no top-level `ingress:` block at all.

Comment: Hi, I have attached ingress section in values.yaml.. please have a look

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with your values.yaml file. It is probable that you have overridden the value of "primary" there. Can you pass any debug steps you have followed so far ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, It is working now. Actually there was a missing value in first line in the ingress yaml,  it 
 should be like this .Values.guacamole.ingress.enabled. The guacamole value i missed to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ramanichandran mentioned in comment section problem is solved by adding a missing value in first line in the ingress yaml. Line should look like:  `.Values.guacamole.ingress.enabled`. The `guacamole` value was missed to add.